# SQL Removing Milliseconds from a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

My Query is:

```
SELECT Symbol, SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(High_Time))) as AvgTime FROM data GROUP BY Symbol;
```

Output:

```
Symbol    AvgTime   
 AAPL  03:34:00.0000
 TSLA  10:50:00.0000
 SHOP  03:40:00.0000
```

How would you change the query so the output looks like this?

```
Symbol  AvgTime 
 AAPL  03:34:00
 TSLA  10:50:00
 SHOP  03:40:00
```

Comment: *Output* Do you see this output in CLI?

Comment: I see this output when using PHPMyAdmin SQL @Akina

Comment: Test the query via CLI. I think that you'll see the output w/o ms, because 4 decimal places is too strange amount...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply apply the ROUND function on the value being converted to a time string eg:

```
SEC_TO_TIME(ROUND(AVG(TIME_TO_SEC(High_Time)))) as AvgTime
```